# Where can I get all the soundtracks from a game like Guitar Rock Tour?

Tags: guitar-rock-tour

I have searched internet archives.... it's easy to get the entire game, but almost never the soundtrack. Soundtracks from old games are vanishing quickly - Bounce Tales, Guitar Rock Tour 2, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you just want a list or if you want to buy the whole thing as an album.
The Wikipedia page of the game gives a list of the songs, but if you want it as an album, I can't help you there, unless you get the songs individually.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guitar_Rock_Tour#Soundtrack
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guitar_Rock_Tour_2#Soundtrack

Comment: Guitar rock had a unique guitar and drums only music soundtracks, which i can't find online